# BASH: Raplace filenames characters that are not on list

Tags: regex, bash, filenames

I want to create a list:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ-._
```

And then iterate trough all files in folder, replacing every character in the file names that is not present in this list with an underscore `_`.

That includes blank spaces.

But using Bash and GNU tools only.

Is that possible?

Comment: This is pretty close http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37398 - you'll probably just need the correct regex

Comment: What should happen if you have two files named `abc(` and `abc)` in the same folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash internals only:

```
for file in *; do
    repl=${file//[!$permitted]/_}
    case $file in "$repl") continue;; esac  # skip if identical
    # Safety: add a suffix to avoid overwriting
    while [ -e "$repl" ]; do
        repl=${repl}_
    done
    mv "$file" "$repl"
done
```

If `$permitted` contains a slash, you will need to backslash-escape it.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that with bash 4, `shopt -s globstar` lets you go recursive with `for file in **/*; do` ?

Comment: this worked very well!  Goota test it more tought to see if there are exceptions.

Comment: As Andrea commented above, you risk overwriting files with similar names.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, right you are!  I added a crude safety measure.

Comment: how can I modify it to make it work recursive with find ? (Keeping the path/folders name intact, sanitizing only the filename)

Comment: @ghoti Suggestion rename filenames to patterns like to folder_filename.ext

Comment: That would be `find ... exec sh -c 'for file; do ... done' _ {} +` provided your `find` supports `-exec` with `+` (if not, try with `\;` instead, though the code could then be simplified but less efficient in that case).

Comment: Or: `for f in * **/*; do [[ $f = *[![:alnum:]_./-]* ]] && mv -v "$f" "${f//[![:alnum:]_.\/-]/_}"; done`

Answer (score 4):

Having the Perl version of the `rename` command, you can use this:

```
rename 's/[^[:alnum:]._-]/_/g' *
```

Comment: `rename` is not a bash builtin.  As far as I can tell, there are two different variations of the command, included in different versions of Linux.  It's not installed by default in FreeBSD or OSX.

Comment: @ghoti More than two.

Comment: @ghoti I never said that it is a bash builtin, at least on Debian it is a Perl script. But, yes seems that there are various versions of that command available on different systems, having different feature sets.

Comment: Can confirm, my rename sucks. It accepts globs and then renames them to a literal string.

Comment: The question asks for "Bash and GNU tools only" so this violates that requirement.  (Not sure why you would have a requirement like that; GNU tools are not ubiquitous either if you strive for portability; although on Linux, they are pretty much a given.)

Comment: Yes, yes... you are right. One thing. (off topic here).. A few days ago we had a conversation about duplicates. This question is surely a kind of a duplicate but should it not being answered? What I want to say is that, especially in the shell related tags, it is a thin gap between duplicate or not. Also the close vote behaviour is not consistent here. Some get closed others not. Also we should think if we really consequently want to close such questions..

Comment: You have a bad regex there: don't put a hyphen (`-`) in the middle of a bracket expression -- you are including a *range* of characters from `Z` to `.`. The perl regex would be `/[^\w.-]/`

Comment: I created a [`bash` chat room](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/64312) once to discuss close votes etc but it never took off. Perhaps now its time has finally come?

Comment: @tripleee Sorry for late response.. Yes, why not. However, atm it shows up as "deleted because of inactivity"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible :)

```
for filename in *; do
    newfilename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ._-]/_/g')
    mv "$filename" "$newfilename"
done
```